# htaccess rewrite giving off .php at the end of a paremeter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have created my own `.htaccess` file which purpose is to change the username URL of my site (along with remove the `.php` extension from **all** urls).

The intent is for the **URL** to transform from:

> www.example.one/profile.php?id=username

to

> www.example.one/username

I know this is a common problem with *"username" htaccess rewrites*, however, none of the answers I have found have helped me solve my problem.

This is my **full** `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# only allow rewriting to paths that dont exist
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# redirect example.one to www.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.one$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.one [R=301,L]

# no php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# example.one/username
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
```

Cheers.

Comment: I would suggest you to use `/profile/{username}`, otherwise many URLs would be interpreted as if there was a username. Ex `/home`, `/about`, etc.

Comment: @AnthonyB that is why I use the second block of code. To prevent actual paths from being mistaken.

Comment: Your block `no php extension` is trying to add the '.php' extension when I try `/username`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# redirect example.one to www.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\?id=([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# no php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# example.one/username
# only allow rewriting to paths that dont exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what do the regex in the second code block (`([^\s&]+)`) and last code block (`([\w=]+)`) do? Cheers

Comment: Thank you, but my question was what are they targeting?

Comment: `([\w=]+)` matches 1+ word or hyphen characters. `([^\s&]+)` matches 1+ non-space, non-`&` characters

Comment: Sorry for the questions. But shouldn't they be targeting only the characters available to users when selecting a username?

Comment: Indeed `[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+` is same as `[\w-]+`

Comment: Oh, didn't know that! Thank you :)